# Two UL's Linked, Click LI and add active to LI in both UL's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 UL's, one of them is my links and the other is the images.

I want to be able to click an LI from one list then for it to display its linked li from another ul. I hope I have explained it well enough.

I have tried to index the uls in order to come up with a solution but no luck so far. See below for my attempt. Any help is truly appreciated. I am fairly new to jQuery.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jbh3q/233/)

```
<ul class="options">
    <li class="active">Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="destination">
    <li class="active">Destination 1</li>
    <li>Destination 2</li>
    <li>Destination 3</li>
</ul>

    $(function(){

    $(".options li").each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('option' + index);
    });

    $(".destination li").each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('destination' + index);
    }); 

    $(".options li").click(function(e){
        $(".options li").removeClass('active');   
        $(this).addClass('active');    
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".options li").each(
    function(index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(".active").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(".destination li").eq(index).addClass('active');
        })   
    }
);
```

You can use the `index` argument of `.each()` to determine the index and save it in an anonymous `.click` function.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KK8Eg/)

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to look at the problem. After trying everyone's solution it looks like this solution by Sergey is the most efficient. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(".options li").click(function(e){ 
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('.destination li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NaFBw/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the simplest way to do it:

```
    $(".options li").click(function(e){
        $(".options li").removeClass('active');        
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        $(".destination li").removeClass('active');
        $('.destination li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jbh3q/243/)